# Collapsing Toolbar Layout inside Fragment Leaves blank Space at Top

Tags: android, android-layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I was working on a Project and when ever i try to add a collapsing layout inside a fragment it leaves blank space at top[image]

As seen in picture below toolbar that is used inside activity once i add collapsing toolbar it leaves this empty space which above orange color.

Here is my code for Fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
         android:layout_height="220dp"
         app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent"
         app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
         app:statusBarScrim="@android:color/transparent"
         >

         <ImageView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="220dp"
             android:background="@color/review_orange"
             android:src="@drawable/icon_collabartion" />



     </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/rcv_showTimings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />







</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Does it remove space on scrolling up ? Try adding android:fitSystemWindows="true" in your fragment container .

Comment: No it adds even more

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: Yes I did, it was a simple fix removing fitssystemwindows

Comment: I haven't set fitssystemwindows in my code then what is the problem?

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Sar : Can you please let me know how u fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you are using one of the `NoActionBar` themes in AppCompat.

You need to put a `Toolbar` in your `CollapsingToolbarLayout`:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
     android:layout_height="220dp"
     app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent"
     app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
     app:statusBarScrim="@android:color/transparent"
     >

     <ImageView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="220dp"
         android:background="@color/review_orange"
         android:src="@drawable/icon_collabartion" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

 </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Comment: Dear Kris, Thank you so much for your help, but I dont want to have toolbar in my fragment. That is the main reason

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question but let me hint you!

You have one Main activity.

You have 10 fragments.

Your Main activity can host the 10 fragments.

As Kris said, you need to keep the toolbar there, you should not move it, then just after creating your fragment, set a listener in that fragment that calls the remaining sequence of initialization inside the activity that cannot be initialized without the creating of the fragment. (Drawer+NavigationView (from activity) with CollapsingLayout containing the toolbar (in your fragment).